# Matplotlib animation with Xarray data

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, python-xarray

I've been stuck on this for a while now. I try to plot my data and animate 12 frames.
this is what my code looks like right now.

```
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from IPython.display import HTML


url = 'https://username:password@nrt.cmems-du.eu/thredds/dodsC/global-analysis-forecast-phy-001-024-monthly?latitude[0:1:2040],longitude[0:1:4319],depth[0:1:49],time[0:1:34],mlotst[0:1:34][0:1:2040][0:1:4319]'
ds = xr.open_dataset(url)
ds.to_netcdf('mlotst.nc') #Make a netcdf-file

cond = (ds.latitude>22) & (ds.latitude<30.5) & (ds.longitude>47) & (ds.longitude<63)
ds = ds.where(cond,drop=True) #Narrowing it down to the coordinates I want

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
#ax = plt.axes(xlim=(47, 63), ylim=(22, 31))
levels = range(90)


def animate(time):
    plt.clf()
    fig = ds.isel(time=time).mlotst.plot(levels=levels, figsize=(10,6))

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, range(13), interval=200, blit=False)
plt.show()


FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter()
ani.save('anim.mp4', writer = FFwriter)
```

It just turns out white. Please help.

Comment: You are making a new figure each time you call `animate`.  Suggest you make an axes and pass that to `plot`

Comment: So I should create empty axes first and then pass the figure to it somehow?.. Do you have any suggestion on how I get this in my function?
Thanks for the answer

Comment: Sure, just pass in `.plot(levels=levels, ax=ax)` where `ax` is your axes.  You could pass `ax` as an `farg` to `FuncAnimation`, or perhaps more simply just make it a global

Comment: I think I figured it out with your help! Many thanks after 24 hours of struggling :)

Comment: I have a problem with my colorbars in my animation. I want to keep the first colorbar for all my figures in animation. I try to do this through setting add_colorbar = time ==0 , as in only for tilmestep 0. But this gives me two colorbars. So when I do this for tilmestep 1 I only get one colorbar( like I want to), but not for the first fram in the animation (frame 0). Any quick fixes to this?

Comment: Do you find any solution? May you can edit or answer your own question, I run into similar problems. Thanks ;)

Comment: Hi sorry! Just saw your comment 5 months later hehe.. Yes! the answer was as "simple" as defining the ax in my figure plot. :)

Answer (score 2):

It was a while ago I wrote this question, but I just saw a comment that wondered about the solution. It was "just" to define the ax =axes basically, then I worked

Working code:

```
levels = range(90)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=[11,8])#ncols=1) #Creating the basis for the plot

def animate(time):
    ds.isel(time=time).mlotst.plot.contourf(levels=levels, ax=axes, add_colorbar= False)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, 24, interval=400, blit=False)


mld= ds.isel(time=0).mlotst.plot.contourf(levels=levels, ax=axes, add_colorbar= False)
cbar= fig.colorbar(mld)
cbar.set_label('Mixed layer thickness [m]')
fig.suptitle("Mixed layer thickness transect. Persian Gulf and Gulf of Oman Jan -19 to Dec -20", fontsize= 18)

#ani.save('animation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps = 2) #Save animation as gif-file

HTML(ani.to_jshtml()) #Show the animation in the kernel
```

Hope this helps someone in the future :)